# How to redirect requests to a static URL until logged in?

Tags: networking

I want to know how to redirect every URL request to a constant URL for authentication.

Once authenticated, the requests should work as usual.

Example:
I have an internet connection. The ISP requires me to first login to its portal and only then can I open any websites.
Like, if I enter a FQDN
**http://www.google.com**
I get redirected to 
**http://myispwebsite.com/login**

How do I achieve that.. I am a noob in networking.

Comment: It's called a "Captive Portal"

Comment: Oh. Okay. Thanks. I just needed the word. I will R&D now.